# Get user information from different database

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, api

I have a big problem I have a main master database which stores the admins information like name, no. etc and also a database name .I am liking a new database with every admin and in that database the admin's  private data will be saved...like one admin whose name is Jack, his data will be stored in master database now he is linked with new database name'jack' in jack database jacks all private tables and his employee details and so on will be saved ...
now when an employee will log in with mobile no. and password how can I search this because there will be thousand of admin and they are linked with thousand of database in which there will lots of employee associated with them. What is  the best technique to search the specific employee with just mobile and password. I was trying that anyhow if I know the admin name then easily i go to his database and fetch his employee details and log in that employee please help me guyz i am working in php and my sql

Answer (score 0):

if you know the admin details you need to use in search box with ajax operation through ajax you need to send the particular employee information i.e., enter into the employee name send ajax through the page ,and getting the employee you need to write a query then you will get particular employee name details. the query is like this .
query is:select(*)from tablename->where('tableusername',fetchusername($username))->get();

Comment: if i know the admin details then there is no issue .. i want to login an employee with is login credentials but there will be lots of database how can i search it for ...i have to search whole database for a single employee and i think that takes too much time